# Unable to call function Network from vis node module in F#

Tags: fable-f#

I'm using vis.js dependency in my Fable-F# project and want to call network function for visualization to display networks. How can I pass the JSON data from F# to Network function?

F# code for importing the module

```
open Fable.Import.React
open Fable.Helpers
open Fable.Helpers.React
open Fable.Helpers.React.Props
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Fable.Import
open Fable.Import.Browser

    [<Import("default", "vis")>]
    let Network (we: React.event)  = jsNative
    let destination = Browser.document.getElementById "app"
    let response = Network destination  JsonData options
```

Vis.js node module code which takes three parameters [Github](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/lib/network/Network.js)

```
  function Network(container, data, options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Network)) {
    throw new SyntaxError('Constructor must be called with the new operator');
  }

  // set constant values
  this.options = {};
  this.defaultOptions = {
    locale: 'en',
    locales: locales,
    clickToUse: false
```

Graph using JS and HTML [Github](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/examples/network/data/datasets.html) for reference

Comment: Is your difficulty trying to create a new instance of Network? Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the vis library you can follow this steps:

1. Go to [@types/vis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vis) npm package
2. Follow the link and copy the content of the `index.d.ts` file
3. Paste it to the left panel of [ts2fable online](http://fable.io/ts2fable/)
4. You can then copy and save the generated definition file in your project (example in `vis.fs`). You will have (at the moment of writing this anwser) 4 errors. You can comments the corresponding lines.

For me:

```
// At the top of the file
type MomentInput = Moment.MomentInput
type MomentFormatSpecification = Moment.MomentFormatSpecification
type Moment = Moment.Moment

// In the middle of it
type [<AllowNullLiteral>] TimelineStatic =
    interface end
```

5. Now you can use the `vis.js` library

Here is the simple network code ported:

```
// Fable demo ported from http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html
module Client

open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Fable.Import

// We import the vis.css style
importSideEffects "vis/dist/vis.css"

// We create an access to the vis library
// We could put it under vis.fs file but it's easier to access it from here
[<Import("*", "vis")>]
let visLib : vis.IExports = jsNative

// Helper to make the code easier to read
let createNode id label =
    jsOptions<vis.Node>(fun o ->
        o.id <- Some !^id
        o.label <- Some label
    )

// Helper to make the code easier to read
let createEdge from ``to`` =
    jsOptions<vis.Edge>(fun o ->
        o.from <- Some !^from
        o.``to`` <- Some !^``to``
    )

// If I was using this library I would probably write some helpers to have something like:
// Node.empty
// |> Node.withId 1
// |> Node.withLabel "My label"
// |> ...
// Like that the code is cleaner and more flexible

// From here this is almost a 1 to 1 with the JavaScript code
let nodes =
    ResizeArray([|
        createNode 1. "Node 1"
        createNode 2. "Node 2"
        createNode 3. "Node 3"
        createNode 4. "Node 4"
        createNode 5. "Node 5"
    |])
    |> visLib.DataSet.Create

let edges =
    ResizeArray([|
        createEdge 1. 3.
        createEdge 1. 2.
        createEdge 2. 4.
        createEdge 2. 5.
        createEdge 3. 3.
    |])
    |> visLib.DataSet.Create

let datas =
    jsOptions<vis.Data>(fun o ->
        o.nodes <- Some (U2.Case2 nodes)
        o.edges <- Some (U2.Case2 edges)
    )

let container = Browser.document.getElementById("elmish-app");

// Because we don't have any option to pass, we need to give an empty object 
// otherwise vis.js failed at runtime
let network = visLib.Network.Create(container, datas, createEmpty)
```